# How to draw 2 functions on a one canvas using Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have the the code below.

And I want to draw 2 lineCharts on the same canvas like here http://prntscr.com/b8oabw

But instead I get this http://prntscr.com/b8o7pg

How to connect all blue parts and all red to make continious lines?

```js
function drawChart() {

            // Create the data table.
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            dataTable.addColumn('string', 'День');
            dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Количество ручных назначений');
            dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Количество отложенных задач');


            @if (Model.ManualAssingDictionary.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var m in Model.ManualAssingDictionary)
                {
                    @:dataTable.addRow(["@m.Key",@m.Value, undefined]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                @:$("#NoManualAssignmentForPeriod").css("display", "block");
            }

            @if (Model.PostponedDictionary.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var m in Model.PostponedDictionary)
                {
                    @:dataTable.addRow(["@m.Key", undefined,@m.Value]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                @:$("#NoStoppedTasksForPeriod").css("display", "block");
            }
            dataTable.sort([{ column: 0 }]);
            
            // Set chart options
            var options =
            {
                'title': 'График количества ручных назначений',
                'width': 800,
                'height': 600
            };


            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
            chart.draw(dataTable, options);


        }


        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Comment: try using `null` instead of `undefined` -- add this to your options --> `interpolateNulls: true`

Comment: @WhiteHat, cool, it's working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the person above said

> try using null instead of undefined -- add this to your options --> interpolateNulls: true

Many thanks to him, it's working.